# Retrieve all documents from ArangoDB collection, with an offset

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is there a way to retrieve all documents, but with an offset? or do I need to specify the amount of doucments i want?

For example:

```
LIMIT 5,"ALL"
```

to retrieve all documents except the first 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "all" option for limit but you can either:

1. Put a large number as the second parameter if you have an idea of the max number records in the table
2. Use the Minus function as follows:

.

```
FOR x IN MINUS (
    (FOR t IN test1
    RETURN t ),
    (FOR t IN test1 
    LIMIT 5
    RETURN t )
)
RETURN x
```

Comment: thats a clever option, using minus, too bad the query has to run twice, but i like it!